# UIPageViewController to Force reload ChildView controller

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I have a slider in Root UIPageViewController which need to pass the slider value to the child View Controller. Which works for other child view controller except than the one already loaded !

I have Slider in RootView for Slider Value Change I have called -

```
- (void)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)slider {
    fontValue = slider.value;
    DetailsVC *dataViewController  = [self viewControllerAtIndex:self.newsIndex storyboard:self.storyboard];
    [dataViewController refreshViewForFontSize:slider.value];
}
```

I have usual Methods of UIPageViewController which works fine. Just the problem is it works only after the ViewDid Load method is called in child ViewControllers

```
- (DetailsVC *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index storyboard:(UIStoryboard *)storyboard {
    // Return the data view controller for the given index.
    if (([self.pageContent count] == 0) || (index >= [self.pageContent count])) {
        return nil;
    }
    DetailsVC *dataViewController      = [[DetailsVC alloc] init];
    dataViewController.fontValue       = fontValue;
    return dataViewController;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution

```
    DetailsVC *dataViewController      = [self viewControllerAtIndex:currentIndex-1 storyboard:self.storyboard];
    dataViewController.textColor = textColor;
    NSArray *viewControllers                    = @[dataViewController];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
```

The currect way to get reload the child viewcontroller is  to get it via

> setViewControllers: direction: animated: completion:

If anyone need a example project I have upload it at 
https://github.com/bishalg/BGPageViewController

[image]